# Specifying formatprg in Emacs' evil mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

In vim, one can set the variable formatprg to have vim use an external program to format lines via the gq command.

Is there an analogous setting for Emacs evil mode? If not, is there another way to achieve a similar functionality?